# python: "while (len(list1)>0) or (len(list2)>0)" doesn't work

Tags: python

Im taking the Google Python Course and I am solving the below problem:

> Given two lists sorted in increasing order, create and return a merged >list of all the elements in sorted order. You may modify the passed in >lists. Ideally, the solution should work in "linear" time, making a single >pass of both lists.

And my solution is below:

```
def linear_merge(list1, list2):
    # +++your code here+++
    a = []
    while (len(list1)>0) or (len(list2)>0):
        if list1[-1] > list2[-1]:
            a.append(list1.pop(-1))
        elif list1[-1] < list2[-1]:
            a.append(list2.pop(-1))
        else:
            a.append(list1.pop(-1))
            a.append(list2.pop(-1))
     #Have to force check
        if (len(list1)==0):
            break
        if (len(list2)==0):
            break
    if len(list1)>0:
        res = (a+list1)
        return res[::-1]
    else:
        res = (a+list2)
        return res[::-1]
```

My issue is even though I check if both lists are empty, I get a list index out of range error. I have to force check if either list is empty at the end of the while loop to prevent the error from occurring.

Why is the while loop failing to correctly see that one of the lists is empty? I am new to python and I am looking for some clarification on why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My issue is even though I check if both lists are empty...

No, you are checking if **either one of them is not empty**.

---

Change this:

```
while (len(list1)>0) or (len(list2)>0)
```

To this:

```
while (len(list1)>0) and (len(list2)>0)
```

And at the end of the `while` loop continue working on the one list which is still not empty.

Comment: BTW, you may as well write it as `while list1 and list2`.

Comment: Well, by checking if both are empty, I mean I wanted to check if either are empty. Once one of them are empty, the code below the while loop checks to add the list that is not empty to return the final sorted combined list

Comment: @AndrewMendez: The first statement inside the loop is `if list1[-1] > list2[-1]`. How on earth do you expect this **not** to throw an `index out of range` exception if one of the lists is empty???

Comment: @barack_manos I totally understand that that statement would throw an index out of bounds when a list is empty, but the while loop is suppose to check  if either list is empty before executing that statement. Why is the while loop not checking the statement to prevent that line of code in executing? I have to do a check at the end of the loop to force check what the while loop statement is suppose to do

Comment: @AndrewMendez: The `while` loop checks if either one of them is **NOT** empty (which means that one of them **can** be empty).

Comment: I see, I was using the wrong logic to check if either list is empty, I need a statement to STOP the loop from executing. Either list will be empty if BOTH list are not empty, so checking if both are not empty will stop the while loop correctly. Thanks!